# Cloudkit sync time when syncing for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to sync data with `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` when I build the app for the first time I try to show loading page based on `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification`
in the documentation says `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` is all responsible for syncing an I don't have access to syncing process
so my problem is I have about 1000 record or less but it takes about 5 min at the beginning when I build the app for the first time (apple rejected my app because of this)
I'm afraid by the time goes and user may add more records to the data it will take more time to sync those data
how can I improve syncing time!

Comment: What was the specific rejection reason? Taking a long time to sync would be a really unusual reason.

Comment: When user installs the app for the first time ever and doesn’t have any data in iCloud I also try to sync data with iCloud which it takes 5 min to sync yeh without any data ( they told me) so I tried not to show the loading and directly send user into the app and update data in the background now UX is better but syncing takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

remember to transfer your development schema to production in cloudkit console before release!